# Blackberry Simulator and authentication

Tags: blackberry, mobile

Is it possible to use a Blackberry simulator version 6 or 7 to browse to a windows authenticated web site?

Specifically, I am hosting a web site on a Windows Server OS, hosted by Internet Information Services (IIS) and the site is setup to require Windows domain, username and password credentials.  This can be via NT Authentication or Forms based Authentication.

Currently, I get unauthorized 401.2 error without getting prompted for credentials.

thx

Comment: what is windows authenticated web site, do you mean Basic Authentication ?